# Improve selection (from 2 options) more Intuitive

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation, interface, options

**NOTE : Feel free to edit the question title to something more accurate, if you feel it fits more.**

Hey all. I'm trying to solve pretty interesting scenario.

I have an app, which creates output from (only) two possible sources. **Video** and **Dynamic Photo**.

In the most intuitive way, in the opening screen of the app, i'm giving the user the option to choose which source i'd like to use in order to create his output. I'm thinking that my current design isn't clear at all, and creates frustration due to the lack of understanding of "whats going on" at this screen. I'm attaching some sample designs. **Would love to hear your suggestions!**

**Tryouts:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest tabs and a bit of rewording to clarify the action the user is taking. Also added a bit of instruction at the bottom.

[image: tabs, rewording, instructions]

*Explanation:* Your wording is "Create Live Wallpaper from Video/Dynamic Photo." When they're finished that is what they've done, but the particular task at hand is to display either the available Videos or Dynamic Photos (plural) in order to select a video/dynamic photo from.

.

Alternatively, the instruction could also be a little pop up that appears upon selection, then fades away.

[image: instruction pop up]

Answer (score 1):

The user chooses one element from a list of elements that can be in either categoryA (video) or categoryB (dynamic photo).

As you have it right now there will certainly be users that will need to do an extra step to change from categoryA to categoryB or vice versa.

In my opinion it is better to **display the elements of both categories at first** and if the user wants to filter and reduce the results then let him do so by selecting categoryA or categoryB.

Comment: Hey Alvaro! Thank you for responding. The main issue is, that the outcome is the same. But the process when choosing Video or Dynamic Photo is completely different + Think about it that way, if both Video and Dynamic Photo is highlighted, the user will think it's a combination of the two, which is wrong. Other suggestions maybe?

Comment: Hi Roi! I see. In that case, as the process is different for each category, maybe it is better not to give preference to any of the two: let the user select from video | dynamic-photo in a previous window and when chosen then he can see the elements of that category.

Comment: In a last-case-scenario solution i might. But i think there is an a good way to achieve what we want in a one-screen. I mean, there is only two options. I'm sure there is a GOOD way presenting those in a clear UX and UI path.

Answer (score 1):

Either of your screen shots look fine to me - it is clear which of the two is selected. This can easily be done badly, to make it ambiguous, but yours steers clear from that.

You might also want to check out [Alternatives for Radio Button?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/102876/alternatives-for-radio-button) - a toggle switch could work for you here.